# How can I detect a new line from fgets then convert it to '\0'?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, fgets

I need to detect if the input is a new line. After that, I need to convert it to `'\0'`. Here is my code:

```
void number()
{
    printf(LEV3"Student No. (20XXXXXXX):\t");
    int x=0, i=0;
    fgets(studno[i], LEN, stdin);
    if('\n'==studno[LEN-1])
        {
        [LEN-1]='\0';
        }
    x = atoi(studno[i]);
    if (((x/10000000)>=21||(x/10000000)<=19))
    {
        printf("ERROR: Invalid Student Number. Format should be 20XXXXXXX.\n");
        number();
    }

    i++;
}
```

How can I do it? I always get a compiler error with this code.

Comment: Adding to @mbratch laundry list. variables that have no declarations (of which I count at least three). That said, [*read the documentation*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) of your apis, and check their results *before* relying on what they do only if they succeeded

Answer (score 0):

Your code as shown has at least a couple of syntax errors.

1. The string in `printf(LEV3"Student No. ...` has that stray "LEV3".
   Is that supposed to part of the format string or what is it?
2. In your `if` that checks for newline, you left off the string name
   when attempting to set a null value in the string. Instead of
   `[LEN-1] = '\0';` you should have `studno[LEN-1] = '\0';`.
3. This function (`number`) calls itself... Eek! Did you mean for this function to be recursive? It's unclear what the purpose is. Your local variable `i` is being incremented as if the next call to `number` will see it, but it won't since it's a local variable. For something like this, you just want a loop, not recursion.

So using @Gangadhar's suggestion, your code ultimately should look like this for reading the line. I'll leave the rest for you to update since I'm not sure what your intention is with `i` etc, and you haven't explained what the format of the input is. I am assuming `studno` is an array of char pointers, but you're not showing it.

```
void number()
{
    printf("Student No. (20XXXXXXX):\t");
    int x = 0, i = 0;
    fgets(studno[i], LEN, stdin);

    if ('\n' == studno[i][strlen(studno)-1])
    {
        studno[i][strlen(studno)-1] = '\0';
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many many problems with the code you posted, and with the code below, but I think it answers your question.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEV3 "\t\t\t"
#define LEN 30
char studno[LEN+1];

void number()
{
  printf(LEV3"Student No. (20XXXXXXX):\t");
  fgets(studno, LEN, stdin);

  int x = atoi(studno);
  if (((x/10000000)>=21||(x/10000000)<=19))
  {
    printf("ERROR: Invalid Student Number. Format should be 20XXXXXXX.\n");
    number();
  }

  int l = strlen(studno);
  if('\n'==studno[l-1])
  {
    studno[l-1]='\0';
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  number();
  printf("'%s'", studno);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1, but although the original code uses recursion on error, I'm not convinced that's a good idea.  Also, `fgets()` is perfectly safe with `sizeof(studno)`; it doesn't write beyond the end of the array and does always write a null byte unless the size is zero.  (And since your code doesn't use the arguments, it is better to define `int main(void) { ... }`.  I like that you explicitly return 0, though.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I freely admit to problems with this code. But if I rewrote the original any further, the poster would not recognize it and it would be less helpful.

Comment: Yes — it is a fine line to draw. The important issue is knowing that `char buffer[SIZE]; if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != 0) { ... }` is perfectly safe — your code 'wastes' an extra byte. The recursion is, as I said, in the original code. The `main()` function definition is an issue if you use a modern enough compiler that complains about unused variables.  It was fiddly because you have to guess so much; the original code was less than satisfactory as an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Answer (score 0):

After using `fgets(buffer,...)`,
1. The buffer ends with the first occurrence of a `\n` and then a `\0`.
2. It could instead end with just a `\0` and no `\n`.
3. The buffer could be unchanged if no input was available or an I/O error.

```
char buffer[N];
if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) == NULL) {
  ; // handle no data read as file I/O error or EOF
}
else {
  size_t len = strlen(buffer);
  // Be sure to check for len > 0
  if ((len > 0) && (buffer[len - 1] == '\n')) {
    buffer[--len] = '\0';
  }
  // use buffer
}
```